# How to show a list of Direct Reports on a User Lightning page?

Tags: lightning, user-record, lightning-record-page

I thought this was straight forward but looks like the User object is built different.

I'm trying to show a list of direct reports for a user if the current user is a Manager (can be taken care using the component visibility filter) on the User Lightning record page.

I added the Related List - Single (standard component) to the page and when I try to look for the Related Lists, nothing shows up.

[image]

I checked the User Profile Layout (previewed) and the User Related List is added to the layout.
[image]

Am I missing something really silly here? Or is this WAD?

Another solution that I can think of is to add a flow which will show a datatable using the current recordId.

Answer (score 0):

Users are indeed limited in a variety of ways. For example, you can't customize the related lists on the page layout, either. A flow should be able to do what you want, or you might look for a Aura/Lightning Web Component that could do this.

Comment: sad! Thanks for confirming.